# Installing nginx on redhat - error missing libpcre.so.0

Tags: rhel, software-installation, nginx

I'm tring to install nginx-1.10.3-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 on redhat7 64 bit.
When I run

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/6/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.10.3-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Package: nginx-1.10.3-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
```

Here is what I tried.

```
sudo yum install pcre pcre-devel -y
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
sudo ldconfig
sudo ldconfig -p|grep pcre

libpcre32.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre32.so.0
libpcre32.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre32.so
libpcre16.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre16.so.0
libpcre16.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre16.so
libpcreposix.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
libpcreposix.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcreposix.so
libpcrecpp.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
libpcrecpp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcrecpp.so
libpcre.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre.so.1
libpcre.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libpcre.so

sudo rpm -Uvh http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/6/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.10.3-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

and I still get the same error.
I do not understand why the ldconfig command is not showing my symlink.
How can I fix the nginx dependency?

Comment: Why are you trying to install a `packages/rhel/6` package on Redhat 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running RHEL/CentOS 7, you'll probably want the 7 packages at http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/7/x86_64/RPMS/, not the ones for RHEL 6.